# Select one of two columns depending on which one matches

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a database table called `friends` with 3 columns: `added_by`, `added_who` and `added_time`.

In the PHP script I try to return the friends of a specific user with a query like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM friends 
WHERE added_by = '$specific_user_id' 
OR added_who = '$specific_user_id';
```

How do I grab the friend's user id since it might be in either `added_by` or `added_who` columns depending on who added who first. I know how to do it the long way like checking if `added_who == $specific_user_id` and if it's true then the friend's id is in the `added_by` column and vice versa but I want to know if there is a faster, better way.

Comment: Are `added_by` and similar rows or columns?

Comment: Perhaps it won't really matter, but which SQL database engine are you using? MS SQL Server, MySQL, postgreSQL, etc?

Comment: If this question has anything to do with PHP, my tip is to insert placeholders and pass data as array: `... WHERE added_by = ?
OR added_who = ?`.

Comment: I am using MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a *CASE* statement. For more information, see the MySQL documentation for [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html).

One example of applying that would be:

```
SELECT CASE added_by WHEN '$specific_user_id' THEN added_who ELSE added_by END as friend_id  
FROM friends 
WHERE added_by = '$specific_user_id' 
    OR added_who = '$specific_user_id';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `IF` statement for this.

```
SELECT *, IF(added_by = '$specific_user_id', added_who, added_by) AS friend_id
FROM friends 
WHERE added_by = '$specific_user_id' 
OR added_who = '$specific_user_id';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query, it is a simple union between the 2 queries you want to make

```
 SELECT added_who FROM friends 
 WHERE added_by = '$specific_user_id' 
 UNION 
 SELECT added_by FROM friends
 WHERE added_who = '$specific_user_id'
```